# The category of l-adic sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I'm currently trying to understand the construction of the category of l-adic constructible sheaves as in SGA5, and it seems that quite a lot of machinery (the MLAR condition, localization of the category of projective systems, etc.) has to be gone through before one can even construct this category and show that it's abelian, for instance. On the other hand it is not even true that the derived category of l-adic sheaves is defined in the obvious manner, since it is defined as a 2-limit of the derived categories of $\mathbb{Z}/l^n$ constructible sheaves.

I understand that the categorical machinery in existence today is a lot more powerful than it was in the 1970's, which makes me curious: is there a cleaner and more transparent way of doing this, and a more modern presentation than SGA or Frietag-Kiehl?

Comment: Other than Ekedahl, "On the adic formalism", I recommend Laszlo-Olsson, "The six operations..., I, II", which made use of Gabber's recent result on finiteness in étale cohom. Their results are more general in that: 1. stacks, 2. over a base more general than a field with finite l-cd and 3. for unbounded derived categories. Note that SGA5 didn't do derived category: just l-adic sheaves. Same issue with SGA4.5 Rapport and Th. finitude; note that under the title "Th. de finitude en cohomologie l-adique" the results are not stated for adic case, but of course this happened after SGA5.

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is, but I'm pretty sure the constructions in SGA only give the "correct" answer when the ground field is either finite or algebraically closed. So one might hope not only for a "cleaner and more transparent way" but also greater generality.

Comment: More recently, Gaitsgory and Luries' book on the Tamagawa conjecture has a section where they develop $\ell$-adic sheaves quite cleanly.

Comment: Maybe you would like to see this https://theses.hal.science/tel-04236971v1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 1.4 in [these notes](http://math.unice.fr/~dehon/CohEtale-09/Elencj_Etale/CONRAD%2520Etale%2520Cohomology.pdf) of Brian Conrad is as nice as one could hope for, given the dryness of the adic formalism.  I don't think the material differs substantially from Frietag-Kiehl, except in that the presentation is much cleaner.  For the derived category stuff, the notes refer to Behrend's paper ["Derived $\ell$-adic Categories for Algebraic Stacks"](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/ladic.pdf) which I haven't looked at really, but a brief skim suggests it contains everything you might desire (constructions in *extremely* general situations), but nonetheless includes examples (!).

Comment: If you ask Behrend for giving you an example, it will end up in sort of new prime numbers, which will be called Behrend's prime numbers!
 

Comment: Thanks. I had seen Conrad's notes earlier, but not Behrend's; this is very nice.

Comment: I'm just going to point out, incidentally, that the (derived?) $\infty$-category of $\mathbb{Z}_l$-sheaves is apparently the homotopy limit  (in the Joyal model structure) of the category of $\mathbb{Z}/l^n$-sheaves. This is one thing that I'd like to understand eventually, but I haven't seen it written up anywhere.

Comment: @Akhil: Perhaps one would prove that (or, say, the $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-analogue) by showing both sides are the derived categories of perverse sheaves, the classical definition having been done by Beilinson and the $\infty$-categorical version amenable to a similar treatment. But it would definitely be nice to have it written up. The limit Deligne takes appears (to me) to work only out of "good luck," (since it's not a real operation in the world of triangulated categories) whereas the homotopy limit is much more natural.

Comment: @Moosbrugger: I'm intrigued by this refinement of Beilinson's theorem, but have never heard it before. (It seems, though, to construct the abelian category perverse sheaves, one must first construct the derived category of $l$-adic sheaves the normal way -- so it would be some kind of bootstrapping.)

Comment: This sounds interesting!  Is there a write-up somewhere?

Comment: @Akhil: I was imagining that a person would construct the derived category of $\ell$-adic sheaves the higher categorical way, then show it has a ``perverse" $t$-structure, show that the heart coincides with the usual perverse heart, and then redo Beilinson's construction to compute Exts. I wouldn't say it's any kind of refinement, but rather a way to show that the smart construction coincides with the usual construction (which is out of laziness: then one doesn't have to reprove all the theorems). 

Comment: I've never seen a write-up about the construction of the derived category of $\ell$-adic sheaves as a homotopy limit, but I think it should follows from HTT 3.3.3.2 and the usual description of the derived category as a 2-limit (see e.g. the first section of Weil II). I don't really know enough higher category theory at this point to be able to work out the details.

Comment: @Akhil: Maybe I misunderstand you, but there's no reason a priori why that 2-limit should have anything to do with the homotopy category of the homotopy limit. (Okay, there's a functor in one direction, but it has no a priori reason to be an equivalence -- one has to use something about the particular situation). As for a construction of the homotopy limit -- I  suggest you try to write it down for yourself as an exercise.

Comment: Brian Conrad's notes are no longer online, but if you e-mail him, he might send you these notes (as I did).

Answer (score 4):

Zheng and Liu are using $\infty$-categories to study constructible sheaves on stacks, and they have a $\ell$-adic version too. (Though most of the details for the $\ell$-Adic version should appear in a second paper that is still in preparation, and I would not call their first paper easy to read. But it is certainly a modern presentation...) Reference :
http://math.columbia.edu/~zheng/bc1.pdf

By the way, they use Gabber's finiteness results, and there is now a nice reference for these too ! (This is really cool.)
http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~orgogozo/travaux_de_Gabber/

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for these links. 